# Why does Ruby have predefined constants TRUE, FALSE, and NIL?

Tags: ruby

Ruby has the predefined constants `TRUE`, `FALSE`, and `NIL` which reference `true`, `false`, and `nil` respectively. Why is this? Why can't people just use `true`, `false`, and `nil`?

Comment: Ruby is redundant by design. Some people like special constants like that to be uppercased; in particular TRUE and FALSE are familiar to the C programming language tradition.

Comment: ruby is built on needs by community.. so if people feel that TRUE & true both adds value... they add it .. Its community driven lang..

Comment: @RussellBorogove Which makes it such a wonderful language to work with `:)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between \`TRUE\` and \`true\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163205/is-there-a-difference-between-true-and-true)

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the nominated exemplar: That question asks what the difference is between the keywords and constants; this question asks _why_ there are both keywords and constants that do the same thing.  That said, this question is on the edge of an opinion question: I think that only the language designer, or someone who was part of early Ruby development, will know the answer.  This question will, unfortunately, gather mere opinions from those who do not actually know, but I hope it remains open in case someone who does know comes along.

Answer (score 0):

ruby have this predefined constants to avoid the mistakes writing it in uppercase and some people like special constants like that to be upper cased so it's just a synonym for the lower case see this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_predefined_constants.htm

Answer (score 0):

it a convenience thing i guess - its same as in say c where people tend to do the same on a project base:

```
#ifndef (TRUE)
#define TRUE (1)
#endif
```

In addition i think defining those constants doesnt cause any harm.