# Is there a difference between `TRUE` and `true`?

Tags: ruby, boolean

There are two instances of `TrueClass`, `FalseClass` and `NilClass` with different names: one in lowercase and one in uppercase. One instance appears to evaluate to the other:

```
true # => true
TRUE # => true
true == TRUE # => true
```

Is there a difference between these two constants, and if so, what are the differences? If they are the same, which of these constants should I use in my code? Should I write `some_value = true` or `some_value = TRUE`?

Comment: Actually, they are not two instances. They are an identical instance referenced in different ways.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that while `true` is a keyword in Ruby, `TRUE` is a constant:

```
true = 1
# => SyntaxError: Can't assign to true

TRUE = false
# => warning: already initialized constant TRUE
# => false

TRUE == true
# => false
```

Comment: Yeah but the constant is initialized to the exact same object reference. They aren't actually different. The problem is trying to apply the English word *same.*  We should be talking about *identity* and *equality.*

Comment: How are you defining "keyword", considering that `true` is a class instance and has an `object_id`? Is `42` a keyword?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `true` is a keyword because [the syntax says so](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/).

Comment: ...@Jörg, it appears that the [keywords for Ruby v2.3.0](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/keywords_rdoc.html) cannot be used as names of variables or methods (i.e., "reserved words"). Could we define keywords as "words" (perhaps not the best term) comprised of letters (uppercase or lowercase) and underscores that have a meaning in Ruby but cannot be used as names for variables or methods?

Answer (score 7):

#### No.

```
true.object_id # => 20
TRUE.object_id # => 20
true == TRUE   # => true
```

But use `true` as the all-caps version is rarely seen and may be confusing.

It's obviously a constant as it's capitalized, but it's a constant that is initialized to the exact same object reference as `true` so it isn't really different. Remember, Ruby variables *and* constants are just object references. Everything is an object.

*Same* and *different* as English words are hard to define. You can argue all day over the meaning of English words. In OOP, we define the concepts of both *identity* and *equality*. In this case, `true` and `TRUE` are both identical and equal. That's why the Ruby equality comparison returns true and why the object IDs are equal.

So I think, given that both of the actual OOP definitions match in this case, we should be able to say *same* as well.  But you don't have to, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no practical difference:

```
true.class # => TrueClass
TRUE.class # => TrueClass
```

You should use

```
variable = true
```

Uppercase is conventionally used for naming constants as such:

```
NUMBER_OF_WEEKDAYS = 7
```

As mentioned in the other answers, there's a catch that I didn't mention:

```
TRUE == true # => true
TRUE = false
true == TRUE # => false
```